# How to simplify association name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

```
# /app/models/service_user.rb
class ServiceUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_user_images
end

# /app/models/service_user_image.rb
class ServiceUserImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_user
end
```

And when I want get all images for a service user I need to call:

```
@service_user.service_user_images
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How I can simplify the name 'service_user_images' to 'images' exactly for ServiceUser model? And should I do it? Are calls like 'service_user.service_user_xxxs' normal for ActiveRecord?

Now I see three solutions:

1) using with the ':class_name' option, but I think that it's overhead for my code and it will make the code dirtier if I have a few associations

2) using with method alias, but I don't think that it's a good solution, because ActiveRecord creates multiple methods for each association and I will be forced to use too many aliases

3) using nested classes like 'ServiceUser::Image', but it creates another difficulties, for example I need to define the name of this class in each factory (I use FactoryGirl), because it translates names like ':service_user_image' to 'ServiceUserImage' by default:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :service_user_image do |image| # works for ServiceUserImage model, does not work for ServiceUser::Image model
    # ...
  end

  factory :service_user_image, class: ServiceUser::Image do |image| # works for ServiceUser::Image model
    # ...
  end
end
```

Ideally I search solution like:

```
class ServiceUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_user_images, alias: :images # JUST EXAMPLE! DO NOT USE THIS!
end
```

**Now I found solution:**

```
class ServiceUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_user_images

  alias_attribute :images, :service_user_images
end
```

It works perfectly and it has no "side effects", which were described by me.

Comment: best solution is using `class_name`, `has_many :images, class_name: "ServiceUserImage"`

Comment: I think the 3rd solution is the better. The translation your denoted seems to be a bad usage of FactoryGirl, I never encountered this.

Comment: Nermin, Thank you for your answer, I think so too. I just was hoping that there is still a better solution, but for now I'll use 'class_name'.

Comment: ForgetTheNorm, Thank you for your answer, I add an example to my post.